# Do items in Buy Back disappear?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

Trying to make some inventory space and a few shards, I sold a few high value items to a merchant and saw I could buy them back.

This is great in case I later need one of these.

I'm wondering though, do they ever disappear, or can I Buy Back the first thing I ever sold a Merchant at the end of the game?

Comment: As I've played more I've noticed that no, not all items you sell are available for buy back, but I haven't bothered tracking if there is a max number or amount of time that causes items to fall off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When selling items to merchants, the only items you are able to buy back are Uncommon (Green), Rare (Blue), and Very Rare (Purple).

After doing some testing, the answer to your question is *yes* - items will disappear from the "Buy Back" menu. You are only able to buy back the last **10** items you have sold to any merchant. There is no way to retrieve any items past the 10 limit.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to Buy Back an item that I had *just* sold to a merchant 5 seconds earlier and it was not present, while some items I'd sold even earlier *were* still present.

So I wouldn't rely on anything still being available for Buy Back at a later date.

Comment: For being unable to buy back immediately, that's probably because the item was gray. I think only green quality and above items qualify for buy back.

Comment: Ah, that could definitely be it.  I didn't know that.